# Geocoding with google maps api v3 is not working when I press ENTER

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

(the whole jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/hlassiege/zbuJb/8/)

Hi,

I'm using google maps api v3 and I try geocode an adress given by the user.
The user can write the name of the city in a text field, and gmap api automatically propose some suggestions :

[image: google map autocomplete]

I geocode the result and display latitude/longitude on two other textfield when the user select something :

[image: latitude longitude updated]

It's easy when the user select the city with its mouse. I just have to catch the event :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
        resetLatLon(inputLat, inputLong, input);
        return;
    }
    inputLat.value = place.geometry.location.lat();
    inputLong.value = place.geometry.location.lng();
});
```

If the user enter "TAB" to move to another field, I listen this event and I try to geocode manually :

```
function tryGeocoding(inputLat, inputLong, input, geocoder) {
var address = input.value;
resetLatLon(inputLat, inputLong, input);
// try to call geocoding manually
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        // pick up the first result, maybe not accurate but better that nothing
        input.value = results[0].formatted_address;
        inputLat.value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        inputLong.value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    }
});
}

$('#location, #city').keydown(function(e) {
    // is user press TAB
    if (e.which === 9  ) {
        tryGeocoding(inputLat, inputLong, input, geocoder);
        return true;
    }
});
```

It works.

However, If the user press ENTER I tried the same logic and it does not work :

```
$('#location, #city').keydown(function(e) {
    // if user press ENTER, the event is not triggered and the location is not correct
    if (e.which === 13  ) {
        tryGeocoding(inputLat, inputLong, input, geocoder);
        return true;
    }
});
```

**EDIT :** It's not so easy. Sometimes, it works, and sometimes not. I really don't understand why the geocoding fails sometimes when I press ENTER but succeed randomly

Comment: you don't need to bind mouse and keys, just use oninput: $('#location, #city').on("input", function(e) { ... i use e.keyCode instead of which, but maybe jQuery homogenizes it anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of a `submit` button is to send the form to the server when you press "enter". 
But because it's also bind to an asynchronous ajax call, sometimes you get the response before the submission, sometimes not, that's why you see different results each time you try.

You need to use `e.preventDefault()`, to stop the submission of the form.

Also, I put your events handlers together: http://jsfiddle.net/zbuJb/10/

Comment: Thanks, it was obvious but I missed that... I've modified your answer to submit the form after the result of tryGeocoding if I type ENTER so that the behaviour is natural for the user.